# How to apply CSS on n-th div in page

Tags: css

I have 4 dynamic divs in a page starting with the same text (dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3, dropdown4). The number changes every time I refresh the page but string "dropown" remains the same.

I want to apply the rule to dropdown4(the number may change on next refresh but div will always be on 4th position in the page.) How do I do that?

I have been using the following code which hides all the divs

```
  div[id^='dropdown']{
     display: none;
  }
```

Just want to hide 4th div, is it possible? Don't want to use JavaScript here, pure CSS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: What's the HTML structure of the page? Are the `<div>` elements siblings? Are they wrapped in other elements?

Comment: I can not post the code, but I can explain it here. I realized later after trying the solutions provided here that the divs are created dynamically on button click.

Basically, I have 4 buttons and each button creates a div, they are not related to each other, divs are not a child  of a button. Divs just share first few chars in their name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:nth-of-type()` selector

```css
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>test1</div>
<div>test2</div>
<div>test3</div>
<div>test4</div>
```

Comment: nth-child wouldn't select nth div on the page. it would select every div that is the nth child of it's parent, regardless of type of other child elements. nth-of-type is the way to go here.

Comment: All the solutions provided works great for the problem I have asked, but I just realized that all the divs are created dynamically so there is not first and last div:( . each div is created on click of a button and they get a random number starting with the same string. I guess I have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

this selector applies formatting to anything ending in what you want.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_end.asp

[class$="box4"] , which selects elements whose class names ends in box4.

If you add div to the area outside:

Div[class$="box4"] it selects any div matching the same case. Hope that helps.